# How does Codeigniter $this->load->any_method() work?

Tags: php, codeigniter

We usually call a method using an object , but here in codeigniter a variable calls method. How did they design it ? and i came across something called super object,how did they make such an object.any help is appretiated.I would like to know how the inner architecture work here.

```
$this->load->view(); //it loads view , how come $this->load an object here
```

Comment: Everything comes from CI_controller

Comment: You can achieve that by using `library` in codeigniter , Also please clarify what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Rajeevbbqq  im trying to know, how the codeigniter framework call a method on a variable. for example $this->load is a varible, it does call methods.. how did they achieve it ? im talking about the inner mechanism

Comment: Simply assign a class to it. `$this->load = new ClassObject(); $this->load->someMethod();`

Comment: Look at the code and figure it out. Or google it. This is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to `/system/core/Controller.php`, you can see below lines, where it all get triggers

```
public function __construct()
{
    self::$instance =& $this;

    foreach (is_loaded() as $var => $class)
    {
        $this->$var =& load_class($class);
    }

    $this->load =& load_class('Loader', 'core');
    $this->load->initialize();
    log_message('info', 'Controller Class Initialized');
}
```

Take look at this as well `system/core/Loader.php`, you can see something like this (related `->view()`)

```
/**
 * View Loader
 *
 * Loads "view" files.
 *
 * @param   string  $view   View name
 * @param   array   $vars   An associative array of data
 *              to be extracted for use in the view
 * @param   bool    $return Whether to return the view output
 *              or leave it to the Output class
 * @return  object|string
 */
public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
}
```